# How to create a list in model class android studio

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

How do I get the list from this model class? I've tried a couple of ways, but program returns nothing. If you can, don't give me complete solution, just give me a hint how to make it. I don't want to have copy + paste project (unofrtunetlly, now it is). I'd want to have this in list, because I'll get the values on all of currencies in textview just for show to user the acutall currency exchange

My model class

```
public class Model {

@SerializedName("base")
private String base;
@SerializedName("rates")
private Rates rates;


public Rates getRates() {
    return rates;
}

public void setRates(Rates rates) {
    this.rates = rates;
}

public void setBase(String base) {
    this.base = base;
}

public String getBase() {
    return base;
}

class Rates {

    @SerializedName("BGN")
    private Double bGN;

    @SerializedName("NZD")
    private Double nZD;

    @SerializedName("ILS")
    private Double iLS;

    @SerializedName("RUB")
    private Double rUB;

    @SerializedName("CAD")
    private Double cAD;

    @SerializedName("USD")
    private Double uSD;

    @SerializedName("PHP")
    private Double pHP;

    @SerializedName("CHF")
    private Double cHF;

    @SerializedName("ZAR")
    private Double zAR;

    @SerializedName("AUD")
    private Double aUD;

    @SerializedName("JPY")
    private Double jPY;

    @SerializedName("TRY")
    private Double tRY;

    @SerializedName("HKD")
    private Double hKD;

    @SerializedName("MYR")
    private Double mYR;

    @SerializedName("THB")
    private Double tHB;

    @SerializedName("HRK")
    private Double hRK;

    @SerializedName("NOK")
    private Double nOK;

    @SerializedName("IDR")
    private Double iDR;

    @SerializedName("DKK")
    private Double dKK;

    @SerializedName("CZK")
    private Double cZK;

    @SerializedName("HUF")
    private Double hUF;

    @SerializedName("GBP")
    private Double gBP;

    @SerializedName("MXN")
    private Double mXN;

    @SerializedName("KRW")
    private Double kRW;

    @SerializedName("ISK")
    private Double iSK;

    @SerializedName("SGD")
    private Double sGD;

    @SerializedName("BRL")
    private Double bRL;

    @SerializedName("PLN")
    private Double pLN;

    @SerializedName("INR")
    private Double iNR;

    @SerializedName("RON")
    private Double rON;

    @SerializedName("CNY")
    private Double cNY;

    @SerializedName("SEK")
    private Double sEK;





    public Double getBGN() {
        return bGN;
    }

    public void setBGN(Double value) {
        this.bGN = value;
    }

    public Double getNZD() {
        return nZD;
    }

    public void setNZD(Double value) {
        this.nZD = value;
    }

    public Double getILS() {
        return iLS;
    }

    public void setILS(Double value) {
        this.iLS = value;
    }

    public Double getRUB() {
        return rUB;
    }

    public void setRUB(Double value) {
        this.rUB = value;
    }

    public Double getCAD() {
        return cAD;
    }

    public void setCAD(Double value) {
        this.cAD = value;
    }

    public Double getUSD() {
        return uSD;
    }

    public void setUSD(Double value) {
        this.uSD = value;
    }

    public Double getPHP() {
        return pHP;
    }

    public void setPHP(Double value) {
        this.pHP = value;
    }

    public Double getCHF() {
        return cHF;
    }

    public void setCHF(Double value) {
        this.cHF = value;
    }

    public Double getZAR() {
        return zAR;
    }

    public void setZAR(Double value) {
        this.zAR = value;
    }

    public Double getAUD() {
        return aUD;
    }

    public void setAUD(Double value) {
        this.aUD = value;
    }

    public Double getJPY() {
        return jPY;
    }

    public void setJPY(Double value) {
        this.jPY = value;
    }

    public Double getTRY() {
        return tRY;
    }

    public void setTRY(Double value) {
        this.tRY = value;
    }

    public Double getHKD() {
        return hKD;
    }

    public void setHKD(Double value) {
        this.hKD = value;
    }

    public Double getMYR() {
        return mYR;
    }

    public void setMYR(Double value) {
        this.mYR = value;
    }

    public Double getTHB() {
        return tHB;
    }

    public void setTHB(Double value) {
        this.tHB = value;
    }

    public Double getHRK() {
        return hRK;
    }

    public void setHRK(Double value) {
        this.hRK = value;
    }

    public Double getNOK() {
        return nOK;
    }

    public void setNOK(Double value) {
        this.nOK = value;
    }

    public Double getIDR() {
        return iDR;
    }

    public void setIDR(Double value) {
        this.iDR = value;
    }

    public Double getDKK() {
        return dKK;
    }

    public void setDKK(Double value) {
        this.dKK = value;
    }

    public Double getCZK() {
        return cZK;
    }

    public void setCZK(Double value) {
        this.cZK = value;
    }

    public Double getHUF() {
        return hUF;
    }

    public void setHUF(Double value) {
        this.hUF = value;
    }

    public Double getGBP() {
        return gBP;
    }

    public void setGBP(Double value) {
        this.gBP = value;
    }

    public Double getMXN() {
        return mXN;
    }

    public void setMXN(Double value) {
        this.mXN = value;
    }

    public Double getKRW() {
        return kRW;
    }

    public void setKRW(Double value) {
        this.kRW = value;
    }

    public Double getISK() {
        return iSK;
    }

    public void setISK(Double value) {
        this.iSK = value;
    }

    public Double getSGD() {
        return sGD;
    }

    public void setSGD(Double value) {
        this.sGD = value;
    }

    public Double getBRL() {
        return bRL;
    }

    public void setBRL(Double value) {
        this.bRL = value;
    }

    public Double getPLN() {
        return pLN;
    }

    public void setPLN(Double value) {
        this.pLN = value;
    }

    public Double getINR() {
        return iNR;
    }

    public void setINR(Double value) {
        this.iNR = value;
    }

    public Double getRON() {
        return rON;
    }

    public void setRON(Double value) {
        this.rON = value;
    }

    public Double getCNY() {
        return cNY;
    }

    public void setCNY(Double value) {
        this.cNY = value;
    }

    public Double getSEK() {
        return sEK;
    }

    public void setSEK(Double value) {
        this.sEK = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see a single class not a list. Have you looked at [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)? Also an appropriate Java Collections class like ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

create an ArrayList object in your activity like this ;-

```
ArrayList<Model> modelList = new ArrayList();
```

now add the data in modelList and use this list where you want.

Comment: leave a comment if your have any query